# Как правильно протестировать автозагрузчик?

Tags: юнит-тесты, php, test-automation

Столкнулся с забавной задачей.
Написал простой автозагрузчик, чтобы мою либу могли подключать даже мамонты через простой `include 'autoload.php';`. Дело осталось за малым: написать тесты на этот автозагрузчик через Codeception (потому что все остальные тесты написаны тоже на нем). И вот тут начинается веселье.
По-хорошему надо загрузить тестируемый класс, отцепить все автозагрузчики через before-хук (обычный `_before()` Codeception или `@before` PHPUnit), попробовать загрузить расположенный в VFS класс и прицепить обратно автозагрузчики, но ведь PHPUnit должен загрузить свой собственный exception в случае провала `assertX()`, а если все уже отключено на уровне `_before()`, то не только PHPUnit не может загрузить свой класс, но и я ему помочь не могу.
Сейчас все сделано довольно убого, через методы `detachAutoloaders()` и `attachAutoloaders()`, между их вызовами через `class_exists('TestNS\TestClass', true)` проверяется загрузка stub-класса, но это какая-то отвратщина.
Как оттестировать этот кейс по-человечески?